# Get a string, denoted by quotes, out of a file with ifstream and get()

Tags: c++, c++11, io, ifstream

I'm trying to parse a file for strings, which are denoted by double quotes in the file.  Once I find a string, I'll store it in a variable and do what I want with it (for the purposes of this question lets just say print it).  My problem is I can't figure out how to get these strings, particularly if they have spaces.
Here is an example of the input:

```
100 20
"String"
"With Space"
'c' ' '
```

Note: The only strings in this input are `String` and `With Space`. All of the other data should be ultimately ignored. Here is my code which is not printing anything at all.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        ifstream input;
        input.open(argv[i]);

        char c;
        while (input.get(c)) {
            if (c == '"') {
                string s;
                while (c != '"') {
                    char letter;
                    input.get(letter);
                    s += letter;
                }
                cout << s << "\n";
            }       
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I've included iostream and fstream. And I'm using namespace std.

Comment: A shame you cannot use C++14 [`std::quoted`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/quoted)... As an aside, *never* use `using namespace std;`. That abomination is just asking for trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this fragment:

```
    if (c == '"') {
        string s;
        while (c != '"') {
```

The `while` loop can never be entered.

You need to read the next character before testing for end of quoted string.

So something like this:

```
    if (c == '"') {
        string s;
        while (input.get(c) && c != '"') {
            s += c;
        }
        cout << s << "\n";
    }
```